# DOM .links Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Sorry if I repeat the question that was asked before, but I can not find a solution for my task. How can I get links from a variable as in the case with document.

Example:

```
var $str = parseHTML ("<td><a>1...<span><a>2...</div><a>2...</table>"),
$x = $("#newDiv");
```

if I appending this variable in the document it's possible to get a links

```
$x.append($str);
```

I can call

```
var $rf = document.links;
```

but how can I get the links without appending directly from variable **$str**

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

`$.parseHTML` returns a jQuery object, and you can use jQuery's DOM methods on it.

```
var $rf = $str.find("a");
```

Comment: sorry but does not work ... probably the same problem, since all the examples that I found with .find(""), are done on the page and not in the variable that includes the HTML code...